# Correct definition of tensor between $2$ vector bundles

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, tensor-products, vector-bundles

Suppose $\pi :E^{m+k} \to M^m$ if a smooth vector bundle of rank $k$ between to smooth manifolds and $\pi' : E'^{m+k'} \to M^m$ be another one. What I want to understand is how $\overline{\pi}: E \otimes E' \to M$ is defined. I know that as a set $E \otimes E' = \bigcup\limits_{p \in M}E_p \otimes E'_p$. My problem is how can we define the smooth structure over this space. I know that we have to use the *a prior* topology defining the trivialization $\overline{\varphi}: \overline{\pi}^{-1}(U) \to U \times (\mathbb{R}^k \otimes \mathbb{R}^h)$ using $\varphi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U \times \mathbb{R}^k$ and $\varphi':\pi'^{-1}(U)\to U \times \mathbb{R}^h$.
What I want to prove is that:

- $\overline{\varphi}_i(\overline{\pi}^{-1}(U_i \cap U_j))$ is open
- $\overline{\varphi}_{ij}$ is a smooth function (here $\overline{\varphi}_{ij}=\overline{\varphi}_j \circ \overline{\varphi}_i^{-1}$)
- with the topology induced by this atlas $E \otimes E'$ is Hausdorff and has a countable basis.
  in such a way we can say $E \otimes E'$ is a smooth manifold.

I appreciate also a reference where these details are filled.

Comment: I think you should worry about proving that it is a vector bundle (or if you already understand that), then there's a more general fact that vector bundles are smooth manifolds. Roughly the key should be that on the base ($M$) you are already assuming smooth-ness, and the "upstairs" part (the directions of $E$ which are not $M$) are just linear, so they are definitely smooth. So it should all work nicely. Lee's intro to smooth mfds book should have the details, unless it gets all pushed to exercises. Look for the vector bundle lemma or around there.